# Unit Tests in Visual Studio 2012: How to prevent Tests from being skipped?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble with debugging my tests. They kept being skipped:

[image]

However, I do ***Analyze Code Coverage***, I get Failed or Passed Test results.

Comment: What do you mean by *tests being skipped*? You set breakpoint, but debugger not stops there when you run some test?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky This is what happened :-[skip test image](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BZ_qQhKCQAAC6mD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Check and remove **[Ignore]** attribute for this test case.

```
[Ignore]
[TestMethod]        
public void DoSelect_ShouldReturnA_SqlDataReader()
{
    // some code...
}
```

Comment: There's no [Ignore] tags in the test. I did a full search

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar behavior if the test has caused an exception in another thread or on that could not be caught.
In previous version of MSTest when an exception was thrown from the Initialize/cleanup methods.

Try debugging the test - if the problem was caused by an exception it would break when the exception is thrown.

Comment: I tried to debug and it didn't even hit the breakpoint at start of the test... Resulting 'Skip Test'

Comment: Could it be that the Test I wrote to test **static** **void** is the issue? I did a **Code Coverage** it gave me results... Bizarre!

Comment: found out the reason. Looks like RhinoMocks is giving issues. Appreciate everyone's help!